# Could not remove WiFi adapter kernel module; Linux hangs

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, freeze, opensuse, wireless-adapter

I am using openSUSE Leap 15.0 (64-bit, kernel version 4.12.14-lp150.12.25-default) with KDE Plasma Desktop (version 5.12.6), all updates applied after installation. I am using a TP-Link T2U wireless adapter, which supposedly has the mt7650 chipset.

For the wireless adapter, I have installed [this](https://github.com/chenhaiq/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916) driver. The one from TP-Link's site doesn't compile (has code errors); other community drivers are apparently built for the mt7610 chipset, hence, the computer completely hangs as soon as the adapter is plugged in.

Anyways, I have compiled and installed the aforementioned driver and can successfully use the wireless adapter and connect to access points and surf the Internet.

This is how I use it:-

1) I plug in the adapter and run, in order:

```
sudo ip link set ra0 up
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

(The adapter is recognised as `ra0`; the system tray tool can't be used unless `NetworkManager` is restarted)

2) I click and open the `NetworkManager` tool in the system tray and connect to the hotspot of my choice.

Now, I can normally surf the Internet. So far, so good!

After I'm done, I disconnect from the hotspot (from the `NetworkManager` tool in the system tray) and then run:

```
sudo ip link set ra0 down
```

The real fun begins here: when I shut down the computer after this, either with the adapter still plugged in or taken out, the computer hangs at the splash screen! I mean, it would be like that forever. If I press `Esc`, to reveal the text messages behind, it would show:

```
...
...
...
[FAILED] Failed unmounting /var
...
...
...
Reached target Shutdown
```

The only way is to hold down the power button to shut it down.

If, after disconnecting from the hotspot (from the `NetworkManager` tool in the system tray) and after setting `ra0` `down`, instead of shutting down, I run:

```
sudo modprobe -r mt7650u_sta
```

or

```
sudo modprobe -rf mt7650u_sta
```

or

```
rmmod mt7650u_sta
```

or

```
rmmod -f mt7650u_sta
```

the console window hangs, i.e., I don't get back the prompt. The rest of the system doesn't hang, though. (The kernel module for this driver is `mt7650u_sta`).

Interestingly, after a fresh boot, if I simply plug in the device but don't set it `up`, I can easily remove the kernel module `mt7650u_sta` and/or the computer shuts down normally. If I never plug in the adapter, the computer shuts down fine, too.

Basically, **it is getting stuck at removing the `mt7650u_sta` module only if the adapter has been set `up` (whether after that I connect to any hotspot or not)**.

How to prevent this from happening and successfully remove the `mt7650u_sta` module even if the adapter has been "used"?
Please note that I am only a novice Linux user. I can't modify any source code by myself, etc.. I would highly appreciate if you give your answers and suggestions in a simple way, so to speak! :-)

---

---

Some extra information:-

After the adapter is plugged in but not set `up`, `ip a` gives

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:22:4d:9f:89:65 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: ra0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

and `lsmod | grep mt` gives

```
mt7650u_sta          1024000  0
usbcore               286720  6 usbhid,ehci_hcd,xhci_pci,mt7650u_sta,xhci_hcd,ehci_pci
```

After the adapter is set `up` and then connected to a hotspot, `ip a` gives

```
...
...
...
3: ra0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 50:3e:aa:89:00:e0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.225.23/24 brd 192.168.225.255 scope global noprefixroute dynamic ra0
       valid_lft 43191sec preferred_lft 43191sec
    inet6 2405:204:42a4:8696:b83c:6cc9:98a4:17ea/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 604788sec preferred_lft 85878sec
    inet6 2405:204:42a4:8696:f7c8:b248:7d11:fdc7/64 scope global mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::db2c:9df4:4de5:1031/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

and `lsmod | grep mt` gives

```
mt7650u_sta          1024000  1
usbcore               286720  6 usbhid,ehci_hcd,xhci_pci,mt7650u_sta,xhci_hcd,ehci_pci
```

Later, after the adapter is set `down`, `ip a` gives

```
...
...
...
3: ra0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 50:3e:aa:89:00:e0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

and `lsmod | grep mt` gives

```
mt7650u_sta          1024000  0
usbcore               286720  6 usbhid,ehci_hcd,xhci_pci,mt7650u_sta,xhci_hcd,ehci_pci
```